# Filling form data by using url extension; Why does this not work?

Tags: php, html, forms, url, web

I have been trying to pre-fill the subject input with information generated in another page, but have been having difficulties with it despite reading a lot of resources about it and seeing examples. I have tried a variety of links, including my most recent attempt with `http://www.myurl.com/folder/index.php/contactform?subject=test`, but even that doesn't work. Anybody have any advice? Also, if you want to test it out before answering, the page experiencing the problem is [the contact page of this website](http://www.theoneestategallery.com/contact/index.php). I've removed information from below to make it more general. Thanks in advance for any and all of the help.

```html
<form id="contactform" method="post">
  <input name="recipient" type="hidden" value="myemail" />
  <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Contacter" />

  <p id="contactname">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p id="contactemail">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p id="title">
    <label>Subject:</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p id="contactmessage">
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </p>

  <p id="submit">
    <input type="button" value="Send" />
  </p>
  <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="myredirectpage" />
</form>
```

Comment: you can fetch the query string data by using $_GET

Comment: Can you briefly explain that or link me something to read about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your page URL is some thing like below

```
http://www.example.net/index.php?var1=Something&var2=10&var3=ok
```

You can use $_GET to get the values of var1, var2,and var3 from the above url

In index.php use the below code to fetch url data

```
echo $_GET['var1'] // Something
echo $_GET['var2'] // 10
echo $_GET['var3'] // ok
```

Go through this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

With php you can do this with a session.
On the other page(not the form) you can do `$_SESSION['subject'] = 'your subject';`
On the form page you can acces this cookie ( make sure you have started the session on top of the page with session_start():

```
  <p id="title">
    <label>Subject:</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" value="<?= $_SESSION['subject'] ?>"/>
  </p>
```

Comment: Although that method is cool and would usually work, it did not in my case. Thanks for the suggestions, and I might look into using sessions at a later time, but that did not work.

Comment: if this doesn't work you have not added session_start() on top of the page. you have to do this on every page you're using sessions. but the $_GET[] wil work good aswell. GL